# Meteor forgot password implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, reactjs

I'm using meteor Accounts package for user management. i want to implement forgot password functionality. for that i'm going to use **Accounts.forgotPassword(options, [callback])**

Here is my client side function to trigger forgot password

```
> forgetPassword = () => {
>   let email = this.refs.email.value;
>   Meteor.call('forgetPassword',email, function(err,list) {
>     console.log(err);
>   });   
>}
```

Here is my server side function

```
forgetPassword: function(email){
    Accounts.forgotPassword({email: email}, function(err) {
       if (err) {
         if (err.message === 'User not found [403]') {
           console.log('This email does not exist.');
         } else {
           console.log('We are sorry but something went wrong.');
         }
       } else {
         console.log('Email Sent. Check your mailbox.');
       }
     });
  }
```

I'm getting below error while i call this functions

```
I20160517-21:33:53.292(5.5)? Exception while invoking method 'forgetPassword' Ty
peError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forgotPassword'
I20160517-21:33:53.293(5.5)?     at [object Object].forgetPassword (meteor://?ap
p/webpack:///C:/wamp/www/avo_eth_v2.1/modules/TruthHurts/server/methods/user-met
hods.js:225:5)
I20160517-21:33:53.293(5.5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (meteor://?app/live
data_server.js:1698:12)
I20160517-21:33:53.293(5.5)?     at meteor://?app/livedata_server.js:708:19
I20160517-21:33:53.294(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (meteor:/
/?app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160517-21:33:53.294(5.5)?     at meteor://?app/livedata_server.js:706:40
I20160517-21:33:53.294(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (meteor:/
/?app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160517-21:33:53.294(5.5)?     at meteor://?app/livedata_server.js:704:46
I20160517-21:33:53.294(5.5)?     at tryCallTwo (C:\Users\sameera\AppData\Local\.
meteor\packages\promise\0.5.1\npm\node_modules\meteor-promise\node_modules\promi
se\lib\core.js:45:5)
I20160517-21:33:53.294(5.5)?     at doResolve (C:\Users\sameera\AppData\Local\.m
eteor\packages\promise\0.5.1\npm\node_modules\meteor-promise\node_modules\promis
e\lib\core.js:171:13)
I20160517-21:33:53.294(5.5)?     at new Promise (C:\Users\sameera\AppData\Local\
.meteor\packages\promise\0.5.1\npm\node_modules\meteor-promise\node_modules\prom
ise\lib\core.js:65:3)
```

How do i implement this functionality. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Accounts.forgotPassword` is a client-side only function. Instead of calling a meteor method, you can just call this function in your client code:

```js
forgetPassword = () => {
    let email = this.refs.email.value;
    Accounts.forgotPassword({email: email}, function (e, r) {
        if (e) {
            console.log(e.reason);
        } else {
            // success
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Great, i was able to fix it. now my concern is once i click reset password link inside my email. i'm getting pop-up model to set my new password. but once i enter my new password and click set password. i'm getting error message saying token expired. please share your thoughts to fix this

Comment: Are you using the built in functionality from `accounts-ui` to handle password resets?

Comment: The 'token expired' error means that you took too long after the password reset to click on the link -- the tokens have a built in expiration period.

Comment: Actually, looking at previous questions about this topic, it looks like the expiration error may occur if someone has already used the token to reset their password (they are one-time-use tokens).

Comment: Actually, i don't think this error occurs due to expiration period exceed or any other issue. i think this is due to i'm not setting Accounts.resetPassword function properly. because when i set this function manually with generated token. it worked. once i come up with generated email's reset like token expiration error showing.